# using probability for rounding decimals

Tags: ruby, math, probability, finance

What might be a simple Ruby way to round numbers using probability, i.e., based on how close the value is to one boundary or the other (floor or ceiling)?

For example, given a current price value of 28.33, I need to add 0.014.

Equivalent to starting with 28.34 and needing to add 0.004, but the final value must be rounded to two decimal places(which can be provided as parameter, or fixed for now).

The final value should therefore be:

- 28.34 with 60% chance, since it is that much closer, OR
- 28.35 with 40% random chance

The reason it occured to me this could serve best is that the application is stateless and independent across runs, but still needs to approximate the net effect of accumulating the less significant digits normally rounded into oblivion (eg. micropenny values that do have an impact over time). For example, reducing a stop-loss by some variable increment every day (subtraction like -0.014 above instead).

It would be useful to extend this method to the Float class directly.

Comment: This is very useful in my financial software when for example, you need there to be a net effect of some repeated action over time, despite that granularity is typically limited at the penny level on the banks' side, and that there is no state memory of any earlier transactions.  Yet, the desired trend is still achieved via probability. Kind of like dithering with random color pixels in graphics when the palette is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
rand(lower..upper) < current ? lower.round(2) : upper.round(2)
```

EDIT:

The above will only work if you use Ruby 1.9.3 (due to earlier versions not supporting rand in a range).

Else

```
random_number = rand * (upper-lower) + lower
random_number < current ? lower.round(2) : upper.round(2)
```

Comment: Yeah possibly. Let me try to extend that to a Float method and see if it works. Might edit your post if it does.

Comment: `rand(28.35..28.36)` dies with `TypeError: can't convert Range into Integer` Know another way to have rand take a range?

Comment: Interesting, works for me in Ruby 1.9.3

1.9.3p125 :065 >   rand(28.35..28.36)
 => 28.359559080867186 

What Ruby version are you using?

Comment: `irb 0.9.6(09/06/30) on ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]` Just confirmed it does work on `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]` (though on wrong server)

Comment: Ah, right, yeah, googling rand in a range is only available in Ruby 1.9.3. Let me edit my answer for other Ruby versions, one sec.

Comment: Edited it for a ruby version agnostic thing, but I much prefer the 1.9.3 syntax!

Answer (score 0):

Wound up using this method:

```
class Float
  def roundProb(delta, prec=2)
   ivalue=self
   chance = rand  # range 0..1, nominally averaged at 0.5
#   puts lower=((ivalue + delta)*10**prec -0.5).round/10.0**prec  # aka floor
#   puts upper=((ivalue + delta)*10**prec +0.5).round/10.0**prec  # ceiling
   ovalue=((ivalue + delta)*10**prec +chance-0.5).round/10.0**prec  # proportional probability
   return ovalue
  rescue  
    puts $@, $!
  end
end

 28.33.roundProb(0.0533)
=> 28.39
```

Maybe not the most elegant approach but seems to work for the general case of any precision, default 2.  Even works on Ruby 1.8.7 I'm stuck with in one case, which lacks a precision parameter to `round()`.

Comment: The whole body of the method could be reduced to a one-liner of course: `((self + delta)*10**prec +rand-0.5).round/10.0**prec`  The long version above improved clarity and ease of testing in irb.